# Is Lebesgue measure a measurable mapping under Fell topology?

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $\mathcal{F}$ is the space of closed set on $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the Fell topology.

Question: Is Lebesgue measure a Borel measurable mapping from $\mathcal{F}$ to the extended real line?

Recall: Fell topology on $\mathcal{F}$ in this case can be characterized by the convergence $d(x,F_n)\rightarrow d(x,F)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, where $d$ is the usual distance between point and set.